# How to retrieve instance attribute names for which the value is true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, data-retrieval

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3. I have an array of symbols and a model class  (`ActiveModel`) having those symbols (more others) as boolean attributes. Given a class instance I would like to retrieve all its attribute names for which the value is `true`. That is:

```
# Given an array of symbols
[:attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3]

# Given a class instance
<#Model attr_1: true, attr_2: false, attr_3: false, attr_4: true, ... attr_N: true>

# Then I would like to return
[:attr_1, :attr_4, ..., :attr_N]
```

How can I make that?

Comment: all attributes return booleans?

Comment: @tokland - Not all attributes related to the given model class return booleans but attributes present in the given array "mapped" to those of the given class return booleans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the list of symbols you can iterate through them and select the ones that are true

```
symbols = [:attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3]
symbols.select {|sym| object.send(sym) == true }
```

If you don't have the list of symbols you want you can simply iterate through all the attributes of the model

```
symbols = object.attributes
symbols.select {|sym| object.send(sym) == true }
```

Comment: you can safely drop `== true`

Comment: Not really, that'd return anything that is not `nil` or `false`, the question explicitly says: "I would like to retrieve all its attribute names for which the value is `true`"

Comment: indeed, but looking at the example we can assume that all values are booleans (probably `something?` methods of ActiveModel). If not, it's a poor example.

Comment: Agreed, but that's not an assumption we should be making without further knowledge of the data model, and since the question asks for only `true` values, I believe it does make sense to include it.

Comment: @tokland - The model class is a `ActiveModel`.

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez heelhook - Is the `send` method less performant?

Comment: Not at all. Its standard ruby and what ActiveRecord uses as well. Its part of the `Object` class of Ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez heelhook - What implementing the same but by using the RoR' [`attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes) method?

Comment: See the second example. Uses that to retrieve the attributes of the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
attrs = [:attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3]

class Model
  def are_true?(attr_names)
    eval(attr_names.map {|a| "send(:#{a})"}.join(" && "))
  end
  def which_true?(attr_names)
    attr_names.map {|a| a if send(a) == true}.compact
  end
end

m = <#Model attr_1: true, attr_2: false, attr_3: false, attr_4: true, ... attr_N: true>

m.are_true?(attrs)  # evals if all given attr_names are true
m.which_true?(attrs) # returns array of attr_names which are true
```